# C# LINQ to SQL 2 Joins

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to join 3 tables together using LINQ to SQL but I am running into an issue. Here is my code.

```
(from table1 in dc.Table1
 join table2 in dc.Table2 on table1.Id equals table2.Id
 join table3 in dc.Table3 on table2.Id equals table3.Id into merged
 from rt in merged.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new { table1.value1, table1.value2, table2.value1, table2.value2, rt.value1, rt.value2 }).ToList();
```

The error I'm getting is

```
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Double which is a non-nullable value type.
```

I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly in the first place. Basically I want to do an inner join on Table1 and Table2 then a left outer join on that with Table 3.

Comment: It sounds like a value in the database that it expects to be a double is null.  Can you add "where table1.Id is not null" or whatever value it is finding to be null?

Comment: try to divide the query in parts - it will help you to specify a part with error. imho that error occurred at "table2.Id equals table3.Id" condition, but I'm not sure. also you can try to re-write it with .Select, .Join, etc. methods instead of LINQ syntax.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the precise solution to your problem. In the future, if you'd like to do that, please post it below, in the answer space. [It's perfectly acceptable to post an answer to your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120215/ended-up-solving-my-own-problem-question-what-to-do-with-the-post?lq=1), and even to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
(from table1 in dc.Table1
 join table2 in dc.Table2 on table1.Id equals table2.Id
 join table3 in dc.Table3 on table2.Id equals table3.Id into merged
 from rt in merged.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new { table1.value1, table1.value2, table2.value1, table2.value2, rt.value1 == null ? 0 : rt.value1, rt.value2 == null ? 0 : rt.value2}).ToList();
```

Comment: This was close. I tired this earlier but got another error. When I revisited it I figured out how to fix it. I will include the working code in my post edit.

Comment: @thecaptain0220 I saw your solution double zero is different than int zero. I forgot to put 0.0. It is good to know that you solved your problem. Thanks.

Comment: The property names were also important for those values. If I didn't have them I got another error.

Answer (score 1):

Regenerate your DB model.

If you have columns in your db that are nullable and they get mapped to value types in .net (`int`, `double`, `decimal`, etc), Linq to SQL will generate them as nullable types, so you won't have to change your linq to sql statements to take the null into account, unless that is actually part of your query.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
    var result = dc.Table1
        .Join(dc.Table2, a => a.Id, b => b.Id, (a, b) => new { Id = a.Id, A = a.value1, B = a.value2, C = b.value1, D = b.value2})
        .Join(dc.Table3, a => a.Id, b => b.Id, (a, rt) => new { a.A, a.B, a.C, a.D, E = null != rt ? rt.value1 : null, F = null != rt ? rt.value2 : null})
        .ToList()
```